# Playwright tests fail when run in bulk but they work individually

Tags: playwright

I'm struggling to figure out why my tests keep failing when they are run in bulk with `npx playwright test` but work fine when I isolate each test individually. I imagine it has to do something with perhaps my fixtures? I'm just not sure what to look for debug the issue.

It's just annoying that I know the tests work, but I don't want to run them one by one. It makes the whole process incredibly slow!

Comment: Hey Richard, it may help if you elaborate more here on the issue how the tests are failing between the two runs and also posting your `playwright.config.ts`. Can you run a single test file, w/ multiple tests, successfully? My first guess is that your tests are not behaving when in parallel, if you try running all playwright tests with the [`fullyParallel`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-fully-parallel) option set to `false`, do you get the same issue?

Comment: First things first. Please share the minimal reproducible code example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's code. There could be thousands of things which may go wrong with it. It's impossible to suggest something meaningful without looking at the code in question.

Comment: Help us in helping you.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, the way I resolved is, see in which statement the test fails. Add some additional navigation statement before the failing statement so that it will not error out when run in parallel. For example, there is a field called Name, then click on the Name text first and then click into that field and then enter the details.

```
await _clickNameFieldText.ClickAsync(); //Click on the "Name" text
await _clickNameField.ClickAsync();//Click into that text field
await _clickNameField.FillAsync("test"); //If fails in this statement then add the above two statements.
```